# backbone JS checkbox

Tags: backbone.js, pug

i have checkboxes on UI written in Jade, and need to check if it's checked or not, but not sure how to do it,

the jade code is:

```
input.checkbox#ddp(type='checkbox', style='margin:0px')
```

the code to check if the checkbox is checked:

```
events:
   'click #ddp': 'checkDesktop'
checkDdp: () ->
  if (@el).find('#ddp').checked
     alert 'found  it 1'
  if ($('#ddp').checked)
     alert 'found it 2'
  if ("input:checkbox[id='ddp']:checked")
     alert 'found it 3'
```

just none of them works, please help, thanks!

Comment: have you tried `$('#ddp').prop('checked')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use

```
$('#ddp')[0].checked; //it is the same that document.getElementById('ddp');
```

Or the jquery selector

```
 $('#ddp:checked');
```

or the method

```
 $('#ddp').get(0);
```

Explanation: Even if you're using a selector by ID, a JQuery Object is used like an array,

Comment: thanks!!! i used $('#ddp:checked'), it works. and i don't know that backbone use JQuery, this whole NodeJs+Coffeescript+Jade+Backbone setting just drive me crazy since the only thing i know is javascript

Comment: then do not use coffeescript :)

Comment: if i can make that decision :(